# Number of pods in a datacenter

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have been looking at the API Reference and haven't found a REST API that will return the number of pods in a datacenter. What REST API do I use to retrieve the number of pods in a datacenter?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this kind of information is not available for customers, so it means that it is not available through API.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m not wrong, the unique way that was able to  get the Pod information is when getting the server information. For example when executing the following:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,locationPathString,primaryNetworkComponent[id,router.hostname],rack]

Method: GET
```

One of the servers has the following response:

```
[
  {
    "hostname": "207819wpapp000",
    "id": 87000,
    "locationPathString": "dal05.sr02.rk92.sl19",
    "primaryNetworkComponent": {
      "id": 480000,
      "router": {
        "hostname": "fcr02a.dal05"
      }
    },
    "rack": {
      "id": 196045,
      "name": "92",
      "statusId": 2
    }
  },
```

Pod information is:

```
"router": {
        "hostname": "fcr02a.dal05"
      }
```

**Where:** fcr02a => POD02; dal05 =>DALLAS05

I hope it helps you.